# What format does a date column have to be in from pandas to upload into Big Query as a date instead of a time stamp?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I have been uploading `pandas` dataframes into our `BigQuery` instance and notice every time I have a date time column, it uploads into `BigQuery` as a timestamp.  This can be a pain when trying to join on a date to tables that are already there and have the data type as date instead of timestamp.

I'd rather upload as a date from the outset instead of having to cast the value to a date.  Does anyone know what date format the column should be in to upload from my python environment to BigQuery as a date and not timestamp?

This is the function I use to upload my data frames:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery 
def upload_results(df, schema, table):
    """Upload tabular data to BigQuery
    
    df: dataframe to upload as a table
    schema: schema table is in
    table: table in BiqQuery to upload
    """
    
    print("inside upload_results")
    print(df.shape)
    
    data2 = df
    object_cols = data2.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns
    
    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client("gcp-sc-demand-plan-analytics")
    job_config = bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig()
    # set write_disposition parameter as WRITE_APPEND for appending to table
    job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
    
    print(client)
    table_id = f"gcp-sc-demand-plan-analytics.{schema}.{table}"
    
    print(f"table_id for this run is: {table_id}")
    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(data2, table_id, job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request.
    
    job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.
    print('Table Created Successfully')
```